# Set fan speed by RPM on Thinkpad T420s in Linux

Tags: linux, fan, thinkpad, acpi

The only interface I've found for setting the fan speed with the thinkpad-acpi module, is setting pre-defined levels, 0-7. Example:

```
sudo su -c 'echo "level 2" > /proc/acpi/ibm/fan'
```

I would like to set the fan speed by RPM and not by pre-defined levels. Level 2 is 2000 RPM, and level 3 is 3500 RPM. I would like my fan to run at about 2500-3000 RPM (at a certain temperature level, of course). Does a RPM based interface exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that it's dependent on the hardware's firmware. As the [README page](http://ibm-acpi.sourceforge.net/README) says:

> Most ThinkPad fans work in "levels" at the firmware interface.  Level
>   0 stops the fan.  The higher the level, the higher the fan speed,
>   although adjacent levels often map to the same fan speed.  7 is the
>   highest level, where the fan reaches the maximum recommended speed.

and

> On the X31 and X40 (and ONLY on those models), the fan speed can be
>   controlled to a certain degree.  Once the fan is running, it can be
>   forced to run faster or slower with the following command:
>
> ```
> echo 'speed <speed>' > /proc/acpi/ibm/fan
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Thinkfan http://thinkfan.sourceforge.net/ seems to be commonly used (it's mentioned a lot in the lenovo forums) whilst it's not RPM based it does allow switching between the preset fan speed levels based on customisable temperatures.

Additional solutions are listed here:

- http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_control_fan_speed
- http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/ACPI_fan_control_script

Comment: As you say, Thinkfan essentially does `echo "level 2" > /proc/acpi/ibm/fan` too. I've already automated the changing of fan speeds, I just want level 2.5 :)

Answer (score 2):

TPFancontrol supports fixed RPM:s, see [TPFancontrol](http://www.staff.uni-marburg.de/~schmitzr/donate.html). It also supports variable fan RPM:s. 
I have used it on three different Thinkpads (X61s, T400s, T410s) works great.

Comment: The tag of question is Linux, this app is not Windows only.