# How can I manage the fan speed on a Lenovo thinkpad t510?

Tags: fan, thinkpad, overheating, speedfan

How can increase the speed of the fan on my Lenovo Thinkpad t510 running  Windows 7?

Is there any software or script that helps me with this?

Comment: Why do you think you should increase it?

Comment: I'm guessing based on his tags that his system is overheating. Have you dusted out the system with a can of air yet? Laptops are very susceptible to insulation by way of dust because of their compact nature. I'd blow out the fan, heatsink and vents first.

Comment: see this question http://superuser.com/q/352187/147104

Answer (score 1):

Fan control on laptops is somewhat rare and requires custom software (speedfan is mostly for desktops).

Try TP fan control
www.rkostadi.org/main/?p=46

you can also try the advanced settings of windows 7 power profiles  , but this rarely does much in my experience.