# Thinkpad T410 Fix fan noise

Tags: fan, thinkpad

How do I fix the fan noise on Thinkpad laptops?  The fan is overly loud.

More specifically how do I fix the fan noise on a T410 Thinkpad?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I manage the fan speed on a Lenovo thinkpad t510?](http://superuser.com/questions/482641/how-can-i-manage-the-fan-speed-on-a-lenovo-thinkpad-t510)

Comment: Also related: [Set fan speed by RPM on Thinkpad T420s in Linux](http://superuser.com/q/352187) and [Notebook fan spinning at max after trying Linux](http://superuser.com/q/469831)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a software called [tpfancontrol](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tp4xfancontrol/) and set it to smart mode.

It keeps the fan much quieter then the default settings.